# Handle Commas While Reading Text?

Tags: python, file-processing

My code is trying to read all log files throughout the specified directory in `rootDir` and write certain pieces of information from that log file to an `outputFile`

The issue I'm having is `searchObj_Archive_date.group()`, `fullpath`,`zDiscsVar`,`zCopiesVar`, and `searchObj_Year_3or6.group()` aren't being read into my file from certain lines within the log files. This happens for only about 10% of the total outputted lines of text, so I'm confused why it's only happening some of the time, so instead of `E:\filepath\text.txt |  5/23/2015 12:00 | C:\anotherFilePath\text.txt | 23 |    23 |    5Year`, I get `E:\filepath\text.txt | | | | |`

Any insight as to why this error is occuring would be greatly appreciated. My code is below:

After doing some researched, I found that what's causing my error is that whenever a line has a comma `,` in it. It stops reading the line at that comma and skips to the next line, does anybody know a workaround to this?

An example of my input text that's giving me problems: `11/23/2015 12:34:58  Adding file D:\fp\fp1\fp2\text, text, text.txt`

Normally these lines don't have commas, so does anyone know of a way to handle commas when reading in lines of text?

```
import os
import re

fo = open('outputFile', 'w')
fo.write("Col|Col|Col|Col|Col|Col \n")
# 1.walk around directory and find log file in one of folders
rootDir = "C:\\Users\\"
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir, topdown=False):
for filename in files:
    fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
    if (filename=="text.txt"):
        # 2.open file. read from file
        fi2 = open(fullpath, 'r+')
        fi2Content = fi2.read()
        zDiscs = re.search(r'(\sNumber of copies: (\d{1,2}))', fi2Content, re.M|re.I)
        if zDiscs:
            zDiscsVar = str(zDiscs.group(2))
        zCopies = re.search(r'(Number of Discs in Set: (\d{1,2}))', fi2Content, re.M|re.I)
        if zCopies:
            zCopiesVar = str(zCopies.group(2))
        fi = open(fullpath, 'r')
        # 3.parse text in incoming file and use regex to find PATH
        for line in fi:
            #4.write path and info to outgoing file
            m = re.search(r'(Adding file(.*))',line)
            if m:
                searchObj_Adding_file = re.search(r'[A-Z]:\\.+', line, re.M|re.I)
                searchObj_Archive_date = re.search(r'^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', line, re.M|re.I)
                searchObj_Year_3or6 = re.search(r'\dyear', line, re.M|re.I)
                if searchObj_Adding_file:
                   fo.write(searchObj_Adding_file.group() + "|")
                   fo.write(searchObj_Archive_date.group() + "|")
                   fo.write(fullpath + "|")
                   fo.write(zDiscsVar + "|")
                   fo.write(zCopiesVar + "|")
                   fo.write(searchObj_Year_3or6.group() + '\n')
#5. close file
fo.close()
fi.close()
fi2.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed my commas before searching the line of text. To do this, I inserted `lineWoCommas = line.replace(',', '')` after `if: m`

Comment: You could put it right after `for line in fi:` and make it `line =  line.replace(',', '')`

Comment: A potential problem with this approach is that it will incorrectly remove commas from filenames (which are legal, but uncommon, filename characters in Windows).

Comment: @martineau Do you have any other solutions in mind? I could use `line = line.replace(',', '(comma)')`, so the user knows where commas use to be.

Comment: That might be OK, and you could even change `'(comma)'` back to `','` before writing matches to the files. However,  probably the best approach would be to modify your regular expressions so they match even when the commas are there (assuming you know the places where they might appear that wasn't part of a file name.